# Is it possible to get parse of Caused by of java log in Logstash confilg?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

```
2016-06-02 17:00:32<ERROR><CommonsHTTPTransportSender:361>: 
org.apache.abcd2.abcdFault
    at org.apache.abcd2.abcdFault.makeFault(abcdFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.abcd2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:83)
    at org.apache.abcd2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.sendUsingOutputStream(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:358)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: com.my.application.IOException: null
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1692)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.close(BaseStreamWriter.java:288)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamWriterWrapper.close(XMLStreamWriterWrapper.java:46)
    at org.apache.abcd2.WriteTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:79)
    ... 27 more
```

So now if i want to get values like LOGLEVEL classname and caused by i got the value for loglevel and class name but not getting the Caused by message.. how it is possible?

Below is my config file.

```
input{
    file{
         path => "D:\Log\application.log"
         start_position => beginning

         codec => multiline{
         pattern => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}"
         what => "next"
         negate => true
        }
    }
}
filter{

        grok{

            match => ["message","^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}<%{LOGLEVEL}><(?<JavaClass>.*[:].*)>"]
        }
        mutate {
        gsub => ['message', "\n", ""]
        gsub => ['message', "\t", ""]
        }
}
output {
        stdout { }
        elasticsearch {
            index => "ABCD_%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

    }
}
```

**My main concern is to parse timestamp loglevel classname and causedby values**

Comment: It sounds like your multiline is not working properly. Can you update your question and append your stdout (rubydebug) ?

Comment: multiline is working fine as i can see in elastic output it take multiline event as a single event..is it possible to skip the other data between..while parsing thru grok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your multiline codec is wrong, that is why your config is not working. (I have tested it).

This is the stdout (that you didn't post) of your config when I use it on my box:

```
artur@pandaadb:~/dev/logstash$ ./logstash-2.3.2/bin/logstash -f conf2/
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 8
Pipeline main started
{
    "@timestamp" => "2016-06-22T09:19:01.896Z",
       "message" => "2016-06-02 17:00:32<ERROR><CommonsHTTPTransportSender:361>: ",
      "@version" => "1",
          "path" => "/home/artur/tmp/logstash/in2/test.log",
          "host" => "pandaadb",
     "JavaClass" => "CommonsHTTPTransportSender:361"
}
```

See how your message does not even have any info? There is nothing to match because your mutliline is not working. I expect this is a problem with first:

- your pattern does not reflect matching the beginning of a line
- When you negate the pattern you should do a "previous" not a next.

So here is a working config (I am using the multiline filter not the codec):

```
multiline {
                pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}"
                negate => true
                what => "previous"
        }
```

With this, I can update your grok to take in the cause:

```
grok {
        match => ["message","^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:ts}<%{LOGLEVEL:log}><(?<JavaClass>.*[:].*)>.*Caused by:%{GREEDYDATA:data}"]
    }
```

And running it with your input on my box, I get:

```
artur@pandaadb:~/dev/logstash$ ./logstash-2.3.2/bin/logstash -f conf2/
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 8
Defaulting pipeline worker threads to 1 because there are some filters that might not work with multiple worker threads {:count_was=>8, :filters=>["multiline"], :level=>:warn}
Pipeline main started
{
       "message" => "2016-06-02 17:00:32<ERROR><CommonsHTTPTransportSender:361>: \norg.apache.abcd2.abcdFault\n    at org.apache.abcd2.abcdFault.makeFault(abcdFault.java:430)\n    at org.apache.abcd2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:83)\n    at org.apache.abcd2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.sendUsingOutputStream(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:358)\n    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)\nCaused by: com.my.application.IOException: null\n    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1692)\n    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.close(BaseStreamWriter.java:288)\n    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamWriterWrapper.close(XMLStreamWriterWrapper.java:46)\n    at org.apache.abcd2.WriteTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:79)\n    ... 27 more",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-06-22T09:22:38.227Z",
          "path" => "/home/artur/tmp/logstash/in2/test.log",
          "host" => "pandaadb",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "multiline"
    ],
            "ts" => "2016-06-02 17:00:32",
           "log" => "ERROR",
     "JavaClass" => "CommonsHTTPTransportSender:361",
          "data" => " com.my.application.IOException: null\n    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1692)\n    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.close(BaseStreamWriter.java:288)\n    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamWriterWrapper.close(XMLStreamWriterWrapper.java:46)\n    at org.apache.abcd2.WriteTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:79)\n    ... 27 more"
}
```

Hope that helps.

For future reference, with regards to logstash questions, it is always helpful to have an example taking stdin and printing to stdout simply because it can be reproduced quite quickly.

Also output of stdout (rubydebug) will tell you exactly what your original message was and makes it easy to see that multiline did not work and that be the cause of your issue.

Cheers!

Artur

Comment: Thank you for your answer! let me check

Comment: No worries - you should be able to take my multiline filter and put it into the codec.

Comment: And what if i have multiple Caused by messages in my log

Comment: I would have to try it, but the above grok should match the first "caused by" and put everything else into the field

Comment: No it takes my last caused by

Comment: use instead: match => ["message","^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:ts}<%{LOGLEVEL:log}><(?<JavaClass>.*[:].*)>(.*?)Caused by:%{GREEDYDATA:data}"]

Comment: That might have something to do with your stacktrace then. I tested it by copy pasting your exception multiple times, hence causing more caused-by clauses. The change in the grock makes the capture not greedy, so it would stop at the first caused by